# Selecting products by multiple color swatches?

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is the ability for a potential customer to select a product based on not one, but two colors by using a color picker, or a swatch of some sort. An example of what I'm after can be found [here](http://www.aussiepacific.com.au/mens) in the sidebar to the left. I've seen multiple modules offering color pickers & swatches, however they all seem to only support one color, not two (or more). The example in the link I gave places selected colors into the URL.

What I'd really like to know is if there's a extension/plugin that can achieve this (I've search extensively but there's always the odd extension that no-one can find) or if it's going to require me manually adding this feature into Magento. If there is no module, is there any way to achieve what I'm after via a few attributes?

I'm using the latest version of Magento CE (1.7.0.2).

**Example scenario:**

```
Bob wants a shirt with black and red colors on it.

He selects black as the primary color.

The search results then show every shirt that has black on it.

He then selects red as the secondary color.

The search results then show every shirt that has black & red on it.
```

Any answers given will be highly appreciated! I've been racking my brain trying to think of the most efficient way to do this but have drawn blanks.

Answer (score 1):

The website you use as an example is using this extension:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pre-select-colors-plus-swatches.html

Then instead of just creating one attribute, 'COLOR' they are creating two: "Primary Color" & "Secondary Color"

Then setting them to Use In Layered Navigation.

From there it is just simple sorting. For instance on that site, you can sort by secondary color only or primary color only.